# Should Join Tables typically be created as Index Organized Tables (Clustered Indexes)?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, indexing, clustered-index

Generally speaking ... should join tables (i.e. associative tables) be created as Index Organized Tables (Oracle) , Clustered Indexes (SQL Server) .... or plain old heap tables (with separate indexes on the 2 columns).

The way I see if, the advantages are:

Speed improvement.
You're avoiding a heap table look up.

Space Improvement.
You're eliminating the heap table altogether,  so you're probably saving ~30% space.

The disadvantages:

Index Skip Scan (only applies to Oracle) .. will be faster then a Full Table Scan, but slower then an Index Scan. So searches on the second column of the compound key will be slightly slower (Oracle), much slower (MSSQL).

A Full Index Scan will be slower then a Full Table Scan - so if most of the time the Cost Based Optimizer is doing Hash Joins (which don't take advantage of Indexes) ... you could expect worse performance. (Assuming that the RDBMS doesn't first filter the tables).

Which makes me question whether any type of indexes are really required for Join Tables, if you're predominately going to be doing Hash Joins.

Comment: You should have a composite primary key on the 2 columns which will create a unique index on them anyway.

Comment: reg "Full Index Scan will be slower then a Full Table Scan": Oracle has also the INDEX FAST FULL SCAN which is basically as fast as a full table access. See http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/explain-plan/oracle/operations#index_fast_full_scan . See also my comment reg. Hash Join Indexing below.

Comment: @MarkusWinand - Good point ... Thanks for the great website (IMO it's most concise dbms agnostic source on indexes online).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My personal rule-of-thumb is to create two-table associative entities as index-organized-tables, with the primary key constraint being the access "direction" I expect to be more commonly used.  I'll then generally add a unique index to cover reverse order of the keys, so in all cases the optimizer should be able to use unique-scan or range-scan access.

Three-table (or more) associative entities generally require significantly more analysis.

Also, the optimizer will use indexes with hash join operations; generally fast full scans, but indexes nonetheless.

Answer (score 3):

I'd just list and talk through a few possible solutions, which hopefully will help you decide.  A "union table" contains two or three columns.  A foreign key to the left table, say `a`, and a foreign key to the right table, say `b`.  The optional column is the row identity for the "union table", say `id`.

**Solution 1: Columns `a,b`.  No clustered index (a heap), indexes on `(a,b)` and `(b,a)`**
Both columns are stored in three places. It supports seeks on both `a` and `b`, and the seek for `b` does not require a bookmark lookup, since `a` part of the `(b,a)` index.  Decent choice, but the triple storage seems like a waste.  The heap has no use but has to be maintained during `insert` and `update` queries.

**Solution 2: Columns `a, b`.  Clustered index on `(a,b)`, index on `(b,a)`**
All data is stored twice.   Can serve seeks on `a` and `b` without a bookmark lookup.  This would be the best practice approach.  It trades disk storage for speed.

**Solution 3: Columns `a, b`.  Clustered index on `(a,b)`**
All data is stored only once.  It can serve a seek on `a`, but not on `b`.  Going from the right to the left table will require a table scan. This trades speed for disk space.  (Your question mentions hash join.  A hash join always does a full scan.)

**Solution 4: Columns `id, a, b`.  Clustered index `(id)`, index on `(a)` and `(b)`**
Seeks on `a` or `b` both require a bookmark lookup.  Both `a` and `b` are stored twice on disk, once in their own index and once in the clustered key.  This is the worst solution I could think of.

This list is by no means exhaustive. Solution 2 would be a good default choice. I'd go for that unless another solution proved itself to be significantly better in tests.

Comment: agreed, except the hash-join thingy. Hash join can use indexes for independent where predicates. There is probably no independent where predicates in such a join, so that the statement might be correct for this case. But it depends on the actual query. See http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/join/hash-join-partial-objects

Comment: @Andomar: I like the analysis. How about a 3-table association? Would indexes on `(a,b,c) - clustered`, `(b,c,a)` and `(c,a,b)` be ok?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the Oracle terminology, but for SQL Server the question is worded in a way that's confusing. To clarify:

- A clustered index determines the physical order of the table
- A nonclustered index is basically a copy of the main table, ordered by the assigned keys
- You can assign ("include") additional columns in the nonclustered index, which can allow the query optimizer to use those columns to satisfy queries, rather that doing a bookmark lookup.
- A heap is a table without an index of any kind. All queries to a heap require a scan.
- A full nonclustered index scan is faster than a full table scan, provided that the index is narrower than the table and that you don't need bookmark lookups.

So, with that in mind, keys used for joins should usually have either a clustered or a nonclustered index associated with them, to avoid table scans. You can include additional columns in your nonclustered indexes as needed -- and prefer clustered indexes for queries that cover a contiguous range of key values with access to many columns per row.